# How to disable Dell Inspiron 1545 touchpad operate with Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mouse, touchpad, dell-inspiron

The mousepad or touchpad in Dell Inspiron 1545 drive me crazy. It moved to other places unexpectedly. I took me more time to retype password or rewrite my programs, my documents.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. Tried install gpointing-device-settings but it was not work. It did not recognize the touchpad.

Comment: Is there a Fn key to turn off the touch pad?

Comment: No Fn key to turn off the touch pad.

Answer (score 1):

Try `synclient TouchpadOff=1`

I wrote an ON/OFF script some time ago but my old opera blog is closed. You can search for it on this [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130311145821/http://my.opera.com/patkoscsaba/blog/) page but you will need to go back to 2010 or so.

Comment: It did not work on my Dell INSPIRON 1545 and Ubuntu 10.04. The Touchpad is running but when you execute xinput list or synclient -l, you don't see any Touchpad device. 

I got this message: "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?" when execute synclient TouchpadOff=1 or synclient -l

If I go to System -> References -> Mouse, no tab for Touchpad.

Comment: Probably you have an Alps touchpad ... sorry, I don't know how to configure that one.

Comment: The script is offline due opera is closing some service. you might want to post it again.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer. You will need to find the post though by yourself in web.archive.org.

Answer (score 1):

From this [thread](http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9394095), based on this [article](http://www.linuxine.com/2008/06/how-to-disable-touchpad-in-ubuntu.html) :

> First edit your xorg configuration
>   file:
>
> 1. Alt+F2
> 2. Type **gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf**
> 3. Find the line that says **Section InputDevice**
> 4. Under that section add a line that reads: **Option "SHMConfig" "on"**
> 5. Save and close that file
>
> Now to turn it off:
>
> 1. Alt+F2
> 2. Type "synclient touchpadoff=1"
> 3. Hit enter and you're done
>
> To turn it back on:
>
> 1. Alt+F2
> 2. Type "synclient touchpadoff=0"
> 3. Hit enter and you're done

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution to the infamous problem of not being able to disable the Inspiron's touch pad after I upgraded from Vista to Win7 32bit.

I had to install an older touchpad driver to make this work.  The driver is Dell R165804, this driver is labeled "Dell Touchpad Driver for XP/2K and Vista 32" when I installed it in my Inspiron 1545 it added the Dell Touchpad tab to my mouse settings under the control panel. Then I opened the control panel, clicked "mouse",  under the Touch Pad tab click on the picture of the touch pad.   I was then able to click "Device Select" and check the box that says "Disable Touchpad when external USB device is present".

Now when the USB mouse is attached the touchpad is disabled and I don't have my cursor jumping around while typing due to my fat thumbs touching the mouse pad.

Hope this helps someone else out there!

Comment: We are talking about Ubuntu here, nothing to do with Windows drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Many answers tell you to go to the control panel, find the mouse and pointers window, and turn off the touch pad. Problem is, there is no "touch pad" icon. Same for going to the task bar and clicking on the touch pad icon. Not there either. Here is how you fix it.

On the internet, go to "Dell Drivers"
Enter your service tag code (look on the bottom of your computer for the service tag and or serial number.
Once you do that, you will be directed to the available drivers for the 1545.  Select "Input" and three drivers will come up.
Select ALPS DRIVER  R270497.exe  and download it.
Once downloaded, run Setup and install the driver. You will have to restart to activate after installing. 
Then look at the task bar. A new icon will be there, called "Touch Pad". Right click on that and you will find a box to check that says: "Disable touch pad when external mouse is detected. 
Now you are in business without that damn touch pad jerking your pointer all over the place when you type.

Comment: We are talking about Linux here, nothing to do with Windows drivers.