# Disable Touchpad by pressing a button

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, touchpad, button-remapping

I would like to disable the touchpad while I'm typing. There are various questions on behalf of this topic already:

[How to disable Dell Inspiron 1545 touchpad operate with Ubuntu 10.04?](https://superuser.com/questions/178167/how-to-disable-dell-inspiron-1545-touchpad-operate-with-ubuntu-10-04)

[Mousepad enable button](https://superuser.com/questions/659366/mousepad-enable-button)

Apparently you can use a simple shell command to enable and disable the touchpad. How do I map this script to a button ?

It would be great if some combination like ctrl + alt + space could be used to turn the touchpad on and off.

My machine is a Thinkpad T540p running on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind keys using the utility `xbindkeys`. Run

```
$ xbindkeys -k
```

and press the key combination you would like to bind. It will output something like this:

```
"NoCommand"
    m:0x1 + c:199
    Shift + XF86TouchpadToggle
```

Then to bind it you copy that text into `~/.xbindkeysrc` like this:

```
"synclient TouchpadOff=`synclient -l | grep -ce TouchpadOff.*0`"
    m:0x1 + c:199
    Shift + XF86TouchpadToggle
```

Just run `xbindkeys` at the terminal to enable it. You can set this up to run automatically by adding an entry to `Applications > Other > "Startup applications"` in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as a command under the hotkey tab of the keyboard configuration for the desktop environment you use. There are probably other ways, but it's the way I wanted mine set. Thanks for sharing the link to the command, I had been looking for something like this for a while.